# Trouble Understanding Fermat's Little Theorem for Non-Coprime Case

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, congruences

For the case where some integer, $n$ is coprime to a prime modulus, $p$, I have proven and understood Fermat's Little Theorem as it is nothing more than Euler's Theorem applied to a prime modulus.

For the case where some integer $n$ is not coprime to $p$ 
$$ \gcd(n,p) \neq 1 \implies p | n $$
This would mean that 
$$ n \equiv 0\mod p.$$
So far so good.
But how does one then go from here to $$0 \equiv n^p \equiv n \mod p$$
as is done by Herstein on page 44 of topics in algebra.

Any help or way-pointing is more than appreciated.

Comment: If $p\,|\,n$ then the congruence is obvious, no?  $p$ divides both sides.

Comment: It is more common to start with Fermat's little theorem and consider Euler's theorem as a generalization. In fact, the case $p|n$ is trivial.

Comment: @Peter, it is the order in which Herstein presented them.
Perhaps it is because Herstein is an introductory group theory text and not a number theory book. 
I understand your point that starting with Fermat makes more sense and will try to think of them in this light.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 
$$\begin{align}{a\equiv b\mod p,\\c\equiv d\mod p,}\end{align}$$

then
$$ac\equiv bd\mod p,$$

since $n\equiv n\mod p$ so in your case
$$n*n*n*\dots\equiv0*n*n*\dots\mod p,$$

given $n\equiv0\mod p$, so
$$n^p\equiv0\equiv n\mod p.$$

Comment: How $n$ be equivalent to both $n \mod p$ and $0 \mod p$ ?

Comment: @JakeXuereb: Sorry I don't understand what's your confusion part. You should stick to the definition: $a\equiv b\mod p$ means $(a-b) = p*k$, which $k$ is an integer. So clearly $(n-n) = p*0$.

Comment: Perhaps you are correct and I'm just getting muddled up in the notation.

Comment: @JakeXuereb: Take a break may help. $a\ \mathbf{mod}\ p$ is different from $a\equiv b\mod p$, you should be careful about this part. The former is the remainder of $a$ divided by $p$, while the latter is the relationship between $a$ and $b$.

Comment: So personally I prefer to use $a\equiv b\ (\textrm{mod}\ p)$ than yours.

Answer (score 1):

Both sides are then divisible by $p$, so their difference is too.

Comment: With reference to which line ?

Comment: Your last congruence.

Comment: If $n$ is 0 mod $p$, then so is $n$ to any power

Comment: @AshwinIyengar then why not have $n^p = 0 \mod p$ ?

Comment: @JakeXuereb The equation $$n^p\equiv n\mod p$$ holds for every $n$, therfore this equation is what Fermat's little theorem actually means. If $p|n$, then we of course have $n^p\equiv 0\mod p$ and if $p$ does not divide $n$, we can reduce to $n^{p-1}\equiv 1\mod p$

Comment: That's the exact same statement.

Comment: @AshwinIyengar could you explain how they are the same ? It might be the case that I am unfamiliar with this convention.
Are you guys saying that 
$$ n \mod p \equiv 0 \mod p $$ 
if so why ?